Selenium with Typescript and Chromium
I'm wondering what forBrowser I'm supposed to use in Typescript if I'm using Chromium as a browser. forBrowser('chrome') doesn't work. I confirmed Selenium works with the setup I have (I made a test Python file that worked), but my app is in Typescript. Maybe forBrowser isn't what I'm supposed to use and I have to reference the Chromium browser differently? Here's the line I'm referring to:
let driver = new webdriver.Builder().forBrowser(webdriver.Browser.CHROME).build()

Here is the Python code that works:
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service as ChromiumService
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from webdriver_manager.core.os_manager import ChromeType

service = ChromiumService(executable_path="/usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromedriver")
options = Options()
options.add_argument('--headless=new')
options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=options)
driver.get("https://python.org")
print(driver.title)
driver.close()

Compared to the Typescript syntax I have (where forBrowser('chrome') doesn't work):
let driver: WebDriver|null = null

let options = new chrome.Options()
options.addArguments('--headless=new')
options.addArguments('--no-sandbox')
options.addArguments('--disable-dev-shm-usage')

driver = new Builder()
  .forBrowser('chrome')
  .setChromeOptions(options)
  .build()

I also tried adding this:
options.setChromeBinaryPath('/usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromedriver')

but that didn't work, either.
And I found another doc where I tried this code (which seemed more similar to the Python code):
let driver: WebDriver|null = null

const options = new chrome.Options()
options.addArguments('--headless=new')
options.addArguments('--no-sandbox')
options.addArguments('--disable-dev-shm-usage')

const service = new chrome.ServiceBuilder()
  .setPath('/usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromedriver')
  .build()

driver = chrome.Driver.createSession(options, service)

but that also didn't work.
I installed Selenium and Chromium on an Ubuntu arm server.

I figured it out! The below code works.
let driver: WebDriver|null = null

const options = new chrome.Options()
options.setChromeBinaryPath('/usr/bin/chromium-browser')
options.addArguments('--headless=new')
options.addArguments('--disable-dev-shm-usage')

const service = new chrome.ServiceBuilder('/usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromedriver')

driver = new Builder()
 .forBrowser('chrome')
 .setChromeOptions(options)
 .setChromeService(service)
 .build()

